# retrieving table entries only from sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a option on my web app to show the last 5 submissions. But only by the Post ID. Not by every table within the post ID if that makes sense. So when someone clicks 'recent submissions' it shows them 5 Id numbers not every single table in the id.

Comment: does the table have any sort of timestamps on it indicating the order the records where inserted in it??

Comment: ok people submit information that goes into the DB. However would like to click on a link that shows the last 5 recent submissions but only to display the id numbers not every table from the submission. I have it all in place to test it but currently I am showing all tables. proves it works but I don't need to see all tables

Comment: yes it has the created_at

Comment: modify your questions with the relevant code in your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(5)
```

if you require only the id of the last 5 elements, then do as below:

```
@first_five_posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).pluck(:id)
```

#### VIEW

```
<%= @first_five_posts %>
```

Comment: and i assume this is in the controller. However I tried this and it prints the last 5 but all of the table in the last 5, around 22 in each. I only require the last 5 id numbers.

Comment: @user3216968 - add `.pluck(:id)`

Comment: do I need to add anything in the view as I'm getting a blank screen

Comment: @user3216968 yes you need to add something to your view, and I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm new to rails... one minute I think I got my head around it the next I just go blank...  However that works a treat so thank you very much for your help.